# How do you crop an image in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

I have a photo app where you can add stickers in one section.  When you're finished I want to save the image.  Here is the code that I have to do that.

```
if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, 2.5);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
}
CGContextRef contextNew=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[self.view.layer renderInContext:contextNew];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now the image that gets saved is the full screen of the image, which is fine, but now I need to crop the image and I don't know how. You can see the image at the link below:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19130454/Photo%202012-04-09%201%2036%2018%20PM.png

I need to crop:
91px from the left and right
220px from the bottom

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I haven't explained things clearly, please let me know and I'll do my best to re-explain.

Comment: This might be a good source for you: [Open Source Library To Add Image Cropping Into An iOS App Quickly](http://maniacdev.com/2011/10/open-source-library-to-add-image-cropping-into-an-ios-app-quickly/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Cropping API for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087435/image-cropping-api-for-ios)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about something like this

```
CGRect clippedRect  = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+91, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width-91*2, self.view.frame.size.height-220);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], clippedRect);
UIImage *newImage   = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: This ignores image orientation because UIImage supports it but CGImage does not

Answer (score 4):

Following code may help you.

You should get the correct cropFrame fist by below method

```
-(CGRect)cropRectForFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // NSAssert(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, @"content mode must be aspect fit");

    CGFloat widthScale = imageview.superview.bounds.size.width / imageview.image.size.width;
    CGFloat heightScale = imageview.superview.bounds.size.height / imageview.image.size.height;

    float x, y, w, h, offset;
    if (widthScale<heightScale) {
        offset = (imageview.superview.bounds.size.height - (imageview.image.size.height*widthScale))/2;
        x = frame.origin.x / widthScale;
        y = (frame.origin.y-offset) / widthScale;
        w = frame.size.width / widthScale;
        h = frame.size.height / widthScale;
    } else {
        offset = (imageview.superview.bounds.size.width - (imageview.image.size.width*heightScale))/2;
        x = (frame.origin.x-offset) / heightScale;
        y = frame.origin.y / heightScale;
        w = frame.size.width / heightScale;
        h = frame.size.height / heightScale;
    }
    return CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Then you need to call this method to get cropped image

```
- (UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)image toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // you need to update scaling factor value if deice is not retina display
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,
                                           /* your view opaque */ NO,
                                           /* scaling factor */ 2.0);

    // stick to methods on UIImage so that orientation etc. are automatically
    // dealt with for us
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y)];

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I am looking for since a week. It works super fine!

Comment: Can we get the same for UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill content mode?

Answer (score 3):

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(CGRect)rect
{
    //create a context to do our clipping in
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //create a rect with the size we want to crop the image to
    //the X and Y here are zero so we start at the beginning of our
    //newly created context
    CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextClipToRect( currentContext, clippedRect);

    //create a rect equivalent to the full size of the image
    //offset the rect by the X and Y we want to start the crop
    //from in order to cut off anything before them
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * -1,
                                 rect.origin.y * -1,
                                 self.size.width,
                                 self.size.height);

    //draw the image to our clipped context using our offset rect
    // CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, drawRect, self.CGImage);
    [self drawInRect:drawRect]; // This will fix getting inverted image from context.

    //pull the image from our cropped context
    UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Note: this is autoreleased
    return cropped;
}
```

Comment: what is self.CGImage?

Comment: My using this method my image is cropped correctly as expected. But it got inverted automatically. Can you help me with it thankx.

Comment: @user2534373 try to remove this
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: self.CGImage is meant to mean image.CGImage

Comment: Try adding this to compensate for the vertical flip: 
`CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);`

Answer (score -1):

Refer the below link for crop image

https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View

```
** How to Use **

Very easy! It is created to be a drop-in component, so no static library, no extra dependencies. Just copy ImageCropView.h and ImageCropView.m to your project, and implement ImageCropViewControllerDelegate protocol.
Use it like UIImagePicker:
- (void)cropImage:(UIImage *)image{
    ImageCropViewController *controller = [[ImageCropViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
- (void)ImageCropViewController:(ImageCropViewController *)controller didFinishCroppingImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage{
   image = croppedImage;
   imageView.image = croppedImage;
   [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)ImageCropViewControllerDidCancel:(ImageCropViewController *)controller{
    imageView.image = image;
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please add some content from the link.

Comment: hi my self ramani one help.. my project crop image like  face shape image also many different type shape crop  and crop view move and scale for objective c