# Crop a UIImage that has been zoomed and rotated

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app where I take a photo, then zoom/rotate the photo. How can I crop the result to the screen's frame?

For example, say I am displaying a photo that is 1000px x 1000px. If I zoom in and rotate a bit, I want the resulting UIImage to be... say 800px x 800px (not 320x320). How can I accomplish this? If I use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect and pass in the UIImageView's rect, I get a super-zoomed, small corner of the image.

Comment: Search github, something like https://github.com/genkikondo/GKImagePicker

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you crop an image in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079701/how-do-you-crop-an-image-in-ios)