# Emailed images are being reduced in browser when sent from iPad (iOS8)

Tags: ios, image, ipad, ios8, email-client

Ok, so I have this problem that I cannot seem to fix. The issue has been happening ever since I updated my app to run with iOS 8.

I create images there are sent in an email. Each image is created off context in a Rect with XCode. I have verified that each image is the same width when created and the widths look the same when sending it off the iPad, but in the email, some widths are reduce while some are kept the same. Please note that the images that have reduced widths are taller than the ones that keep their widths in the email.

Here is my log output:

```
2014-10-26 21:45:05.027 [773:217915] Modifying corn footer
2014-10-26 21:45:05.910 [773:217915] Width of image  = 871 for image
2014-10-26 21:45:05.911 [773:217915] Modifying soy footer
2014-10-26 21:45:06.459 [773:217915] Width of image  = 871 for image
2014-10-26 21:45:06.460 [773:217915] Modifying sorghum footer
2014-10-26 21:45:07.257 [773:217915] Width of image  = 871 for image
2014-10-26 21:45:07.258 [773:217915] Modifying wheat footer
2014-10-26 21:45:07.706 [773:217915] Width of image  = 871 for image
2014-10-26 21:45:07.708 [773:217915] Modifying final footer
2014-10-26 21:45:08.042 [773:217915] Width of image  = 871 for image
```

Even though the images are the same size in when sent, they appear as different widths in the browser. This was not an issue before iOS 8.

I would show you the images, but I cannot for privacy reasons.

Here is the method for reducing the image. Each image is the same width going in and going out.

```
-(UIImage*) reducePassedInImage:(UIImage*)image {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width * .85,image.size.height * .85);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    UIImage *reducedPicture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    int width = reducedPicture.size.width;
    NSLog(@"Width of image  = %d for image ", width);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return reducedPicture;
}


-(void)sendTableEmail:(NSMutableArray *)images{

    //start email
    MFMailComposeViewController *email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    email.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    //get farmer name
    NSString *farmerName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<p>For:   %@</p>",self.currentSeedBin.farmerName];

    //get date string
    NSString *currentDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<p>Date of Compiling: %@</p>",[self getDateString]];

    //create html body with images etc
    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString string];
    [message appendString:@"<html><body>"];
    [message appendString:@"<p><img src=\"http://...../images/.....png\" alt=\"ALT MESSAGE\"/></p>"];
    [message appendString:@"<p>Right Product Right Acre Product&trade; Summary</p>"];
    [message appendString:farmerName];
    [message appendString:currentDate];
    [message appendString:@"<p style='width:100%; font-weight:bold;'>*Important: This RPRA&trade; is accurate on the date above. Changes after this date will not be reflected in this Product Summary.</p>"];
    [message appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    //check for default cc address
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaultCCEmail = [defaults stringForKey:@"defaulCCValue"];
    if(defaultCCEmail != nil && ![defaultCCEmail isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSArray *ccArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:defaultCCEmail, nil];
        [email setCcRecipients:ccArray];
    }

    //set header information
    [email setSubject:@"Right Product Right Acre Product\xE2\x84\xA2 Summary"];
    [email setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES];

    //attach images
    int imageCount = 0;
    for(UIImage *image in images){
        imageCount++;
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"RPRAProduct%i",imageCount];
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"RPRA Product Table %i",imageCount];

        file = [file stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
        [email addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:fileName];
    }

    [self presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "browser"? Mobile Safari on iOS device, or email? Also, are you sure the images are all the same height? The email doesn't seem to set any dimensions for the image. Could be they're being displayed to fit & if some are taller then they'd have to shrink the width in order to fit w/the proper aspect ratio.

Comment: The images are the same width, not height. I believe that the height variance is causing the browser to reduce the taller images. It is in any email client on any browser.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. You could try putting something like `width = 100%` on the image tag in the HTML. But, since CSS support is so inconsistent between email clients, a better option might be to crop the images to also make them a consistent height. This previous question has some techniques for doing so that you could incorporate into your `reducedPassedImage` method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087435/image-cropping-api-for-ios

Comment: I already tried the width = 100% in css to no avail. I will look at the link and let you know.

Comment: Don't want to crop the image either.

Comment: If your images have unequal heights, your options are to crop the actual img, or force the width in HTML. Doesn't look like you specify any width or height for the img tag, so try putting an inline `width=500px` or something in the HTML for the img. If that doesn't work, you could try a table-based HTML email (still common because email clients are so different & screwy wrt CSS support).

Comment: I did try the width css tag using percent and actual width. I have not tried the table idea. That is a good one. I will check this out.